# Is it possible to extract numbers and operators out of an array in order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am currently working on making a calculator using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript (particularly jQuery), and I'm trying to set it up so that whenever you click an operator button after inputting a number it will send the number and operator to an array in order.

For example: the user inputs 5 and presses the multiply operator. Upon pressing the multiply button, it will push the 5 and the * to `newArray` like such: `newArray = ["5", "*"]`. Then upon pressing enter it will push the 1 to the end.

My goal is to extract these from the array to make a single expression which ultimately, in the given case, would output 5.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Please note that yes/not questions like this are generally not a good fit for Stack Overflow. You are welcome to ask more specific questions about problems with your code.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to my issue.

Comment: I just answered to the question in the title. Which issue you exactly? You explained what you are trying to do, but you didn't mention at all with which step you have problems with. Stack Overflow is a place where you get help for concrete problems with your code, not where others write code for you.

Comment: "My goal is to extract these from the array to make a single expression which ultimately, in the given case, would output 5." Not starting an argument but I think it was relatively clear what I was asking. At least, Brian understood below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array which results in `"5*1"` and [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) it - [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/9hezs9v5/)

```
var newArray = ["5", "*", "1"]

var output = eval(newArray.join("")) // 5
```